# WPF: How to redefine CanExecute method of ApplicationCommands

Tags: c#, wpf, command

I use standard Cut, Copy and Paste commands (which is part of ApplicationCommands class). Is it possible to redefine CanExecute method?

Here is my code:

XAML:

```
   <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="Copy"
                CanExecute="CopyCanExecute" Executed="CopyExecuted"/>       
    </Window.CommandBindings>

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Name="txt"></TextBox>
        <Button Command="Copy" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=txt}">copy</Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

Code-behind:

```
private void CopyCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = false;
}

private void CopyExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Copy Executed");
}
```

The button still behave like its command is standard Copy command.

Answer (score 1):

You do this via a [CommandBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandbinding.aspx).  The local CommandBinding can specify a CanExecuteHandler.

For details and a working example, see [this blog post](http://en.csharp-online.net/WPF_Concepts%E2%80%94Built-In_Commands).

Comment: Can't uderstand why it doesn't work with Copy\Cut\Paste (example with Help command works fine). I add CommandBinding to Copy and define CanExecute to return false: e.CanExecute = false in code-behind file. But Copy still works like standard Copy command: when I select a text in TextBox the button becomes enabled. Could you help me to understand this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The copy command will not work when the focus is on a textbox where the commands have already been handled, but it will work on elements like CheckBox etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the CanExecute handler you might need to add `e.Handled = true; also, so that it doesnt go and execute the standard Copy.CanExecute()

Comment: e.Handled = true has no effect on this. I also changed e.CanExecute = true, but Click on Button just copied selected text and my MessageBox doesn't appreared

Answer (score 0):

You can set the commandbinding to the textbox directly instead of to the window.